# Cannot calculate decimals in my calculator

Tags: c#, exception, decimal, calculator

So, I have made a calculator in C# but it cannot calculate decimal numbers.
It works perfectly fine when clicking on for example the buttons: 6 then . (this is a dot) then 5. But as soon as I click on the "+"-button (or any other operator) afterwards in the form, the program stops and I get a message saying that

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occured in
>   mscorlib.dll. The input string was not in a correct format".

I don't know exactly how to solve this. Is there anyone that knows how to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
namespace Kalkylator{
    public partial class Form1 : Form{
        String operation = ""; //the operation we will use
        Double resultat = 0; //the result we will get
        bool finished = false; //if false, we have not pressed the "=" button yet

        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //
        private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (finished == true){ //if we press any operator, clear the textbox-window so new numbers can be entered
                textBoxFonster.Clear(); 
            }
            finished = false; //we are not done with the calculation
            Button b = (Button)sender; 

            if (b.Text == "."){
                if (!textBoxFonster.Text.Contains(".")){
                    textBoxFonster.Text = textBoxFonster.Text + b.Text;
                }
            }
            else{
                textBoxFonster.Text = textBoxFonster.Text + b.Text; //writes the number in the textBox
            }
        }

        private void operator_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            operation = b.Text; //the operation we will perform is the operatorButton we will press
            resultat = Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text); //HERE IS WHERE THE PROGRAM GIVES ME THE ERROR.
            finished = true; //we are done with the calculation
        }

        private void clear_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxFonster.Text = ""; //clear the window from all text
            resultat = 0; //clear the value of resultat and set it to 0
        }

        private void LikaMed_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch(operation){
                case "+": //add the result with the text in the textBox
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat + Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "-": 
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat - Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "*": 
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat * Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "%":
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat / Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text) * (resultat/100)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "^": 
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (Math.Pow(resultat, Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text))).ToString();
                    break;
                case "Log": //takes the 10th log of resultat
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (Math.Log10(resultat)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "Sqrt":
                    textBoxFonster.Text = (Math.Sqrt(resultat)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "/": //divide the result with the text in the textBox if that text is not 0. If so, show an error message
                    if ((Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)) != 0){
                        textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat / Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)).ToString();
                    }
                    else{ //show error in MessageBox
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by 0!");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            finished = true; //this will clear the result textbox when clicking another number after the equal sign has been clicked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess, are you in a locale that normally uses a `,` to specify the decimal point?

Comment: On which line exactly? Can you please show an example input and culture settings?

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thank you! You are absolutely right. Did not even think of it and now it works :)

Comment: @chue If you found a solution, you should consider self-answering your question.

Comment: @SonerGönül An example: I clicked on 6.5 and then the + operator, and the program gave me the error right after I clicked on the operator. But it seems that Phylogenesis was right. The problem was that I used `.` and not `,`

Comment: @Codor I'm sorry I don't follow. What do you mean?

Comment: If you ask a question and find a solution to the problem yourself, you can post an answer (containing your findings) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Double.Parse without specifying the Culture.

Change:

```
switch(operation){
    case "+": //add the result with the text in the textBox
        textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat + Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)).ToString();
        break;
    case "-": 
        textBoxFonster.Text = (resultat - Double.Parse(textBoxFonster.Text)).ToString();
        break;
```

to:

```
Double operand1=resultat;
Double operand2=0;
Double.TryParse(textBoxFonster.Text,NumberStyles.Float,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out operand2);
switch(operation){
    case "+": //add the result with the text in the textBox
        textBoxFonster.Text = (operand1 + operand2).ToString();
        break;
    case "-": 
        textBoxFonster.Text = (operand1 - operand2).ToString();
        break;
```

Alternatively, you could actually support multiple cultures, and change this code:

```
        if (b.Text == "."){
            if (!textBoxFonster.Text.Contains(".")){
                textBoxFonster.Text = textBoxFonster.Text + b.Text;
            }
        }
```

to this:

```
        if (b.Text == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator){
            if (!textBoxFonster.Text.Contains(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)){
                textBoxFonster.Text = textBoxFonster.Text + b.Text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can I ask you, how come it is important to specify the Culture? This is my first time hearing about it.

Comment: Because without it, you are going to use the system default culture.  Since your code expects the . to be the decimal separator in some places, you should specify that when trying to parse text to numbers.  Not all cultures use . to specify the decimal separator, and if you run your code on a machine that has a default culture that the decimal separator as , and the thousands separator as ., then double.Parse will parse (1.002 as 1002 and parse 1,002 as 1.002 etc)